# How to find the limit of $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{3x^3+6x^2+45}{5|x|^3+25|x|+12}$

Tags: limits

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\dfrac{3x^3+6x^2+45}{5|x|^3+25|x|+12}$$

Is just a matter dividing all variables by $x^3$ and getting $\frac{3}{5}$?

I tried looking it up and saw the graph doesn't just stop at $0$.

Comment: Yeah that's more or less all there is to it, but be careful with signs!! When $x<0$, $x^3$ is negative, but $\vert x\vert^3$ is positive.

Comment: Absolute values are a pain!  You should always simplify to get rid of them if you can.  (OK. . . maybe not always.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: If $x<0$ then 
$$
|x^{3}|=-x^{3}
$$

$$
|x|=-x
$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $x<0$ we get $|x|=-x$ , therefore $|x|^3=-x^3$ . Hence, the limit becomes :
 $$\
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  - \infty } \frac{{3x^3  + 6x^2  + 45}}{{ - 5x^3  - 25x + 12}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  - \infty } \frac{{x^3 (3 + \frac{6}{x} + \frac{{45}}{{x^3 }})}}{{x^3 ( - 5 - \frac{{25}}{{x^2 }} + \frac{{12}}{{x^3 }})}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  - \infty } \frac{{3x^3 }}{{ - 5x^3 }} =  - \frac{3}{5}.
\
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**, substitute $-x$ for all the $x$ in the limit.

Now instead as $x\to-\infty$, $-x\to\infty$

Hopefully this will help you see the limit more clearly.